# AngularJS: How to send JS object to c# controller via $http post?

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, http, post

Here is my code for AngularJS controller from which i am sending http post request to server:

```
    'use strict';

    var input = {title: "", note:""};

    notes.controller('inputController', function inputController($scope, $http) {


    $scope.cancleInput = function () {
//not yet implemented
    }

    $scope.saveInput = function () {
        input.title = $scope.title;
        input.note = $scope.note;


       $http.post("/saveData/writeData", input);
    }

 })
```

Here is my code inside C# controller:

```
    public class saveDataController : Controller
    {
             public static void writeData(input input)
            {
                var jsonString = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(input);
                //other code
            }

     }
```

The http post call is not recognizing the C# method.
I am pretty sure that my URL is wrong or i am missing any C# attribute.

I am getting following error:
*POST http://localhost:56171/saveData/writeData 500 (Internal Server Error)*

The C# method is not hitting the break point so it is never being called by the post request.

Comment: which js error you are getting ? give your angular js controller declaration code here.

Comment: @ranakrunal9 i added the information to the post that you asked for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did to make it work:

I added custom Api configuration in WebApiConfig file.

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "ActionApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{Action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Then I modified the HTTP Post URL according to the new Api configuration.

```
        $http.post("/api/saveData/writeData", input);
```

Then I made the C# controller inherit from ApiController.
One last change i made was that i added [HTTP POST] attribute to the C# method and removed the static keyword.
(I do not understand why having 'static' in the method definition made the method undetectable by HTTP POST.)

```
  public class saveDataController : ApiController
{

    [HttpPost]
    public void writeData(input input)
    {

       //bunch of code
    }      

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check by getting post data from input stream data in your c# controller. you are getting 500 error because angular $http will post ajax request with "application/json" content type which is not accessible through the Request.Form collection. Try by changing public

```
public static void writeData(input input)
```

to

```
public static void writeData()
```

and use Request.InputStream to get data.

```
var Res = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream);
```

Comment: It is not hitting the break point so the writeData() function is never being called by the post request. I believe something is wrong with my way of sending post request. @ranakrunal9

Answer (score 0):

Try by creating API controller by inheriting from ApiController and decorate method with HttpPost verb as below -

```
public class saveDataController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public static void writeData(input input)
        {
            var jsonString = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(input);
            //other code
        }

    }
```